Is it valid, to write RewriteCond and RewriteRule in the same line?
I have multiple (very much) redirect rules for a site relaunch. I foster them in an Excel table.
Is it valid, to write RewriteCond and RewriteRule in a .htaccess with any other separator, than a new line (\r\n)? Which separators would work?
I would prefer a tab (\t), like
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/?calc_id=2556$\tRewriteRule .* \/ [NE,R=301,L]


No, it is not allowed

Why don't you simply try it and decide yourself?
